# If you had to pick a free CMS to integrate with ASP.NET MVC what would you pick?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, content-management

I am looking for starting from scratch with a CMS - specifically one that will integrate well with ASP.NET MVC.

- preferably somebody has written Html Helpers for me
- must be easily editable by an idiot
- must give me really nice clean HTML
- must be able to store simple strings, or full blown documents
- would really prefer SQL server as the backend - or a webservice interface if it has to be mysql
- must be good for future localization concerns

I know *very* little about these things, and I'm going to explore more CMS questions on Stackoverflow - but didnt specifically find much so far about MVC integration.

Really what I'm looking for initially is advice on whether or not I should get hung up on easy MVC integration as opposed to just lookin for the best CMS.

**Edit:** The kind of content I'll be storing will be resources such as strings, short HTML 'sections' which may describe a product, short descriptions of contests, long documents originally created in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[N2 CMS](http://www.n2cms.com/) has an example site built against an earlier version of MVC, it can be downloaded from [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/n2/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20272) - the source was moved to [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/p/n2cms/) over a year ago, and I found that I needed to download that and recompile it against the latest MVC bits to get it to work.

This is one of the few open source CMSs that I've looked at that I would actually consider a CMS, rather than a "glorified blogging engine" - just my £0.02 though.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is young (not even RTM yet) and there aren't many (or any really, outside of Oxite) pre-built products/solutions for it yet. You could use it to build your own CMS from scratch, but see: wheel.

If you're looking for one that's built already, just go with the one that best meets your needs regardless of platform.

You also don't mention what the CMS is for, which is an important distinction.